# Select option in IE11 is different to one in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, web-applications

The select options is displayed as drop down in IE8 whereas in IE11 some options are up and some are down. And the selected one is at centre. Is it new feature in IE11. Can I have official documentation or link that confirms this feature ?

```
<select>
 <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
 <option value="saab">Saab</option>
 <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
 <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It's probably an enhancement for touch screens. I know OS X does it that way. Maybe Microsoft has seen the light and copied good design :). (BTW, this is off topic.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  A new usability enhancement in Microsoft Internet Explorer 11 to help users maintain their place in long lists in selects ("drop-down menus") is that a previously selected option will appear in the middle of the list of options - some above, some below - when a user clicks on a select again, they don't just all appear in a menu below. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535893(v=vs.85).aspx and http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/iedevcenter/FormControls/scenario5.html